# Installing custom jar maven to local repository

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven and I am trying to add a custom jar to my local repository. In my command I run the following:

```
C:\Users\tj>mvn install:install-file -Dfile= <C:\Users\tj\neon\couponsBasic.jar> -DgroupId=<com.coupons> -DartifactId=<coupons> -Dversion=<1.0> -Dpackaging=<jar> -DgeneratePom=true
```

The jar is in that location but my response is:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there something that I am missing here? 
Should I save the file directly into the M2 folder?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually type the command as you have given in question? Did you type the angular brackets (`<C:\Users\tj\neon\couponsBasic.jar>`)?

Comment: Yes, I typed exactly as above.

Comment: When I remove those brcakets I get an error message that "No plugin found for prefix ('C' in the current project and in the plugin groups...)

Comment: The jar itself is not a Maven project and doesn't have a pom.xml

Comment: You probably need to write it in quotes: `-Dfile="C:\...\"`.

Comment: Could you please try `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\tj\neon\couponsBasic.jar -DgroupId=com.coupons -DartifactId=coupons -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: As I responded above, when I do that I get an error message: "No plugin found for prefix ('C' in the current project and in the plugin groups..)

Comment: What version of Maven are you using?

Comment: Binary zip archive apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip

Answer (score 0):

remove `<` and `>`

```
C:\Users\tj>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\tj\neon\couponsBasic.jar -DgroupId=com.coupons -DartifactId=coupons -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: When I remove < and > I get the following error message '[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 12.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]'